# Beamer: How can I place two figures, one on the right of text and one below the same text?

Tags: beamer

As the question in the title suggests, I'd like to place two figures at different places in a slide using Beamer.

Below I have provided some code I have written, in which I have succedeed placing one of the figures on the right. But, I'm not sure how to place the other figure right below the text.

I'd appreciate any help or hints. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Testing}
\date{}
\subject{Testing with figures}

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.55 \linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Text A
                \item Text B
                \item Text C
            \end{itemize}
    \column{0.4 \linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height = 7cm, width = 4.7cm]{ImageA.png}
\end{columns}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{ImageB.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To align the bottom of the first figure with the top of the second, its added heights must not be greater than the height of the frame. Or you can move the second up by inserting a negative `vspace.`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Testing}
\date{}
\subject{Testing with figures}

\begin{document}
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.55\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Text A
                \item Text B
                \item Text C
            \end{itemize}
            \column{0.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height =0.5\textheight, width =\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{columns}
        \vspace*{-30pt} % comment to align bottom and top of the figures
        \includegraphics[height =0.6\textheight,width =0.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```